# How to change $PATH?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, .bash-profile

I am not able to find 'ifconfig' command, So I need to modify $PATH variable. Can you provide the best way to modify $PATH varible, whenever I logged-in.

```
[aaa@cyclrtp10 ~]$ ifconfig
ifconfig: Command not found.
[aaa@cyclrtp10 ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/software/utils/bin:/usr/software/bin:/usr/software/rats/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
[aaa@cyclrtp10 ~]$ /sbin/ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:82:1E:2C
          inet addr:10.60.250.73  Bcast:10.60.251.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fd20:8b1e:b255:800b:250:56ff:fe82:1e2c/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe82:1e2c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10597755438 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10754394830 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:7987750842424 (7.2 TiB)  TX bytes:6618160592811 (6.0 TiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:5156561681 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5156561681 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:16690172948881 (15.1 TiB)  TX bytes:16690172948881 (15.1 TiB)

[aaa@cyclrtp10 ~]$
```

Comment: this is offtopic, certainly better fitted to Superuser

Comment: You have transferred HOW much data over that poor eth0???

Answer (score 2):

In some Linux distros I have seen `/sbin/` restricted to root's profile. You have a few options.

Executing ifconfig as root:

```
$sudo ifconfig
```

Supplying the direct path on the cli:

```
$/sbin/ifconfig
```

Creating an alias in your ~/.bashrc OR ~/.bash_profile OR ~/.bash_login OR ~/.profile:

```
alias ifconfig="/sbin/ifconfig";
```

Lastly you could add `/sbin` `/usr/sbin` and `/usr/local/sbin` to your existing path variable in whichever config "~/.bashrc OR ~/.bash_profile OR ~/.bash_login OR ~/.profile" that is most convenient for your system.

Simply add:

```
PATH="/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

If you want to add a local bin in your profile as well:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Comment: thanks Gareth for the edit job. I get moments here. kid is 3, need i say more. lol

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `bash` as your shell, modify *`$HOME/.bash_profile`* and add:

```
export PATH="/sbin/:$PATH"
```

with a new loggin, the new PATH will be loaded.

---

If you're using `sh` or `dash`, you should modify *`$HOME/.profile`*

---

You may also want to read [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Independently of your login shell</strike> you can create a .profile file in your home directory and add  (or update an existing .profile file and append) the following line:

```
export PATH=/my/new/path:$PATH
```

Comment: not really, if `bash` finds `.bash_profile` it will stop looking further (ie look for and read `.profile`).

Comment: Correct. For global setting try using /etc/profile file instead (requires root access)

Comment: @c00kiemon5ter: I've rarely seen .bash_profile used in practice. Usually it's plain ~/.profile that includes ~/.bashrc if it exists and if the current shell is Bash. That way Bash-specific features (like command completion) are kept seperate in .bashrc and general things (like PATH) are in the general .profile that is used for all shells.

Comment: I would go the other way around. Use `.bash_profile`, since it will be found first, but source `.profile` from it. That way, you don't need an explicit check in `.profile` to see what the current shell is. (In practice, I only use `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`, and just don't worry about sh-compatibility.)